# Ler arquivo txt e salvar em array PHP

Tags: php, txt

Tenho um arquivo txt, em que os dados são separados por `|`.

Gostaria de ler e separar o conteúdo de dentro de cada par de `|` em uma posição de um vetor. Porém não imprime quando coloco o `print_r` fora do `while`.

```
<?php
    $arquivo = fopen ('arq.txt', 'r');
    $result = array();
    while(!feof($arquivo)){
        $result = explode("|",fgets($arquivo));
    }
    fclose($arquivo);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Então, uma pequena explicação de cada linha para que você possa se situar no próprio código:

```
    <?php
    // Aqui você abre e lê o arquivo
    $arquivo = fopen ('arq.txt', 'r');
    // Aqui você está definindo que a variável é um 'array()'
    $result = array();
    // Você agora irá verificar se existe o arquivo e se o código acim o leu (true|false)
    while(!feof($arquivo)){
        // Aqui foi onde você errou, pois seria '$result[]' e não '$result'
        $result[] = explode("|",fgets($arquivo));
    }
    // Fechando a leitura do arquivo
    fclose($arquivo);
    // Postando resultados
    print_r($result);
?>
```

O código limpo ficaria:

```
    <?php
    $arquivo = fopen ('arq.txt', 'r');
    $result = array();
    while(!feof($arquivo)){
        $result[] = explode("|",fgets($arquivo));
    }
    fclose($arquivo);
    print_r($result); 
?>
```

No caso, você esqueceu de definir que a variável dentro do `while` continua sendo um `array()`, sendo assim ele não irá puxar nenhum resultado.

Comment: Oi Rapha! Obrigado por me ajudar, porém quando tento esse código, que vc gentilmente me passou, exibe o erro 500... Poderia me ajudar??

Comment: Dentro do seu log apresenta algum erro em específico?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Sim, que ele exibe o **500 Internal Server Error** sabemos, mas você viu algum erro dentro do arquivo de log?

Comment: Como estou começando na programação ainda não sei do que se trata esse arquivo de log...

Comment: Editei o código, tente agora, por favor!

Comment: Obrigado por tentar de novo Rapha, porém ainda com erro 500.